# Force saving of id with Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Here's my integration spec:

```
let(:user){ FactoryGirl.build :user }

subject { page }

feature 'authentication' do
    describe 'guest signs up' do
        before do
            sign_up user
        end

        it { should have_title user.user_name }     
        it { should have_link user.user_name, href: user_path(user.id) }
    end
end
```

The spec `it { should have_link user.user_name, href: user_path(user.id) }` fails. Why? The id is wrong.

I've **built** the factory in memory, so it has no id so the spec fails. However, if I give it an id like this:

```
factory :user do
    password = Faker::Internet.password

    id 3
    first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
    last_name { Faker::Name.last_name }
    user_name { Faker::Internet.user_name }
    password { password }
    password_confirmation { password }
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    uuid { SecureRandom.uuid }
end
```

The spec still fails. It's actual id is `10`. This 10 is created by active record I think, and overrides my desire ot have an id of 3.

**How do I get around this, forcing the id?**

**Should I be forcing the id? How should I be testing when user is a built user?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't usefully force the id: the whole point of your spec is to test that a user is created by your controller code (since you're writing an integration spec you probably don't want to stub out the actual saving of the record).

Your controller code won't let you force the id of the created record, (and in the real world you wouldn't want to let users do this), so the setup of your factory doesn't matter.

Since you want to test is that the page contains a link to the show page for the freshly created user, all you need is the id of that user: instead of using the id from the factory built object, use `User.last.id`

It might be an idea to also spec that a new user was actually created (i.e that `User.count` changed)

Comment: What's the best way to update the `user` variable with `User.last.id`? In the before block?

Comment: You don't need to update user - just check that the href is user_path(User.last.id)

Answer (score 0):

Try using FactoryGirl.create instead of build.

Comment: Yeah but I'm signing up the user, and then uniqueness validations would fail.